# Migrating to rails 3.1 gives DEPRECATION WARNING: class_inheritable_attribute is deprecated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Since i migrated from Rails 3.0 to Rails 3.1 i get these warnings :

> DEPRECATION WARNING: class_inheritable_attribute is deprecated, please
>   use class_attribute method instead. Notice their behavior are slightly
>   different, so refer to class_attribute documentation first. (called
>   from require at
>   /Users/vincentdaubry/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@global/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:74)

I do not have any reference to class_inheritable_attribute in my code.

I guess one of the gem i'm using is producing this error, but how can i know which one ? Or is there something else to do to fix this warning ?

EDIT 2 :

None of the gem i'm using has any reference to class_inheritable_attribute (i tried to ack "class_inheritable_attribute" in the gem directory).

**If i deploy my app on another computer on rails 3.1.3 that doesn't use RVM i dont get the warning, so i think it comes from RVM. Does it sound reasonable ?**
I tried to update RVM with rvm get stable but i still get the warning..

Any ideas ?

EDIT :

Here is my gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.3'
gem 'paperclip', '2.4.5'
gem 'pdf-toolkit', '0.5.0'
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '1.2.0'
gem 'delayed_job', '2.1.4'
gem 'devise', '1.5.3'
gem 'mini_magick', '3.4'
gem 'faraday', '0.6.1' #WARNING : this faraday version is specify, because on 0.7.5 this breaks facebook connection
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '2.2.2'
gem 'kaminari', '0.13.0'
gem 'forem', :git => "git://github.com/radar/forem.git"
gem 'forem-redcarpet', :git => "git://github.com/radar/forem-redcarpet"
gem 's3_swf_upload', :git => 'https://github.com/nathancolgate/s3-swf-upload-plugin.git'
gem 'aws-s3', '0.6.2', :require => 'aws/s3'
gem 'jquery-rails', '1.0.13'
gem 'dalli', '1.1.4'
gem 'bson', '1.5.2'
gem 'bson_ext', '1.5.2'
gem 'exception_notification_rails3', '1.2.0', :require => 'exception_notifier'

######################################################################
# unused
######################################################################

#gem 'newrelic_rpm', '3.3.1'
#gem 'mongo',  '1.5.2'
#gem 'mongoid', '2.4.0'
#gem "rdiscount"



######################################################################
# Environment specific
######################################################################

group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
    gem 'rspec-rails'
    gem 'factory_girl_rails'
    gem 'mocha'
end

group :production do
  gem "pg"
end
```

Thanks,
Vincent

Comment: bundler-1.1.3 is causing the warning,  post your Gemfile

Comment: I thought bundler was just detecting some deprecation in one of my gem (?) I edited my question with a copy of my gemfile

Comment: You're correct,  I didn't see the 'require'

Comment: Try a 'bundle update'  which will reload all the gems,  and see if you see the deprecation warning.

Comment: wait, never mind that one,  that will update gems to their latest version,  sorry

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: playing around with RVM was the way to solve this problem if i can recall (Sorry to be so vague, i solved this problem quite a long time ago)

Answer (score 0):

You can grep by code of all installed gems to find all entries of `class_inheritable_attribute`. When you find it, try to update it.

Comment: I tried that in the RVM gem directory and i dont get any reference to class_inheritable_attribute . I also tried to bundle install --path to be sure that i'm searching in all dependencies and no success. If i deploy my app on another computer that doesn't use RVM it doesn't display the deprecation waring so i think it comes from RVM. I'll update my question

Answer (score 0):

It's bundler depreacation. Try update bundler. So far it works well with bundler 1.0.22